# Is it considered bad practice in java for a package to contain both classes and sub-packages?

Tags: java, structure, naming-conventions, package

Is it considered a bad practice in java to have a structure where some package/s contain both classes and sub packages? i.e :

```
com/
  domain/
     SomeClass.java
     AnotherClass.java
     model/
       Model1.java
       Model2.java
     somePackage/
        SomePackageClass.java
```

The other option being `SomeClass.java` and `AnotherClass.java` contained in third package

Comment: That is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's normal structure and not a bad practice. You have different levels in the tree structure. If the class logically is best suited in the parent package then leave it there. If these two classes share a common role that differs them from the others then you can move them to a separate package.